# python global variable inside a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, variables, locking, global

The story begin with two threads and a global variable that change.. a lot of time :)

Thread number one (for simplicity we will call t1) generates a random number and store it in a global variable GLB.

Thread number two (aka t2) check the value of the global variable and when it reaches a value starts to print his value until a period of time.

BUT if t1 changes the value of that global variable, also change the value inside the loop and I don't want this!

I try to write pseudocode:

```
import random
import time
import threading


GLB = [0,0]

#this is a thread 
def t1():
    while True:
        GLB[0] = random.randint(0, 100)
        GLB[1] = 1
        print GLB
        time.sleep(5)


#this is a thread 
def t2():
    while True:
        if GLB[0]<=30:
            static = GLB
            for i in range(50):
                print i," ",static
                time.sleep(1)




a = threading.Thread(target=t1)
a.start()


b = threading.Thread(target=t2)
b.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

The question is: why variable static change inside the loop for? It should be remain constant unitl it escapes from loop! 
Could I create a lock to the variable? Or there is any other way to solve the problem?

Thanks regards.

Comment: `static` shouldn't change in that loop. How about writing a small working example for us to test?

Comment: One problem is that `GLB` may change before you have a chance to assign `static`. Is that what your are seeing?

Comment: @AlejandroSazo `static` is a new reference to the object so it doesn't need to be copied. Since its an immutable `int`, you don't really get a copy anyway.

Comment: @AlejandroSazo never do that before! I search now for that solution should I try with copy.deepcopy() ? Thanks

Comment: `randint` returns an immutable `int`, deepcopy won't help.... is this your real code or is GLB a different type of object?

Comment: my real type object is a list!

Comment: _generates a random number and store it in a global variable GLB_ - a list is a very different thing. You were quite explicit that it was just an `int`. You really need to post a working example. And rewrite the question to state what you are doing.

Comment: ok! give me some times and I'll reinsert the code! just wait for a while, meanwhile thanks :)

Comment: Depending on the size of the list and what `t2` wants to do with it, a copy or a lock to share the single list may be more appropriate.

Comment: I'll write the code with the threads and add the correct object a list! Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GLB` is a mutable object. To let one thread see a consistent value while another thread modifies it you can either protect the object temporarily with a lock (the modifier will wait) or copy the object. In your example, a copy seems the best option. In python, a slice copy is atomic so does not need any other locking.

```
import random
import time
import threading

GLB = [0,0]

#this is a thread 
def t1():
    while True:
        GLB[0] = random.randint(0, 100)
        GLB[1] = 1
        print GLB
        time.sleep(5)

#this is a thread 
def t2():
    while True:
        static = GLB[:]
        if static[0]<=30:
            for i in range(50):
                print i," ",static
                time.sleep(1)

a = threading.Thread(target=t1)
a.start()

b = threading.Thread(target=t2)
b.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I add two time.sleep() to be more explicit. The variable static change inside the for loop while I aspect that is "constant" for all the time is inside the loop!!

Comment: I wrote a working test and `static` doesn't change. Write a test, post it, and prove me wrong!

Comment: Thw two function are inside a thread and t1() change continusly the value of global variable also when I'm inside the for loop of t2(). Is ok if I paste external link to code? using pastebin ?

Comment: Top! I works. static = GLB[:] this is equivalent to static = copy.copy(GLB)?